# What might be this adhesive stuff on my ignition coil connector?

Tags: connector

I just went to swap ignition coils for testing and noticed that the harness connectors are held on with a gummy black adhesive. Removing the connectors effectively removed the adhesive. I'd like to re-adhesive the connectors.

Here are the images:
Undamaged adhesive:
[image]

Damaged adhesive (after swapping):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that the connector's locking mechanism has been broken off (by a previous owner perhaps??) and a makeshift fix was to apply some silicone sealant to keep the connector from coming loose.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking. It is a very weak and gummy adhesive that I don't recognize, and the stuff I have would be way to strong for this application.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a suitable adhesive around and can't buy any (or quickly enough) then I would look at using a zip tie or two to hold the connectors in place.

A bit of ingenuity and a figure 8 or some-such will work.

Comment: A zip tie would certainly work to keep the hard shell connector together... but that won't address water getting inside.  Its hard to tell from the photo if the waterproof integrity is compromised.  If so, tie strap plus a sealer wouldn't hurt..

Comment: Silicone dielectric grease can be used to fill the internal cavities. It keeps the water out. If the location is harsh, use the grease, then the zipties, then wrap with sealing rubber tape.